# How to get Specific Cell Value from Excel With Respect To Row And Column Value using Java POI

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, javafx-2

I have an excel sheet,

i) i want to search first element and suppose the first element is "double" according to the picture,

ii) Then with the same iteration i iterate the first row (i.e. row 0) and i found  "size(in bytes)". Then i want the specific cell value with respect to row and column value i searched above with the iteration i.e."Primitive". How do i get that using Apache POI.
Please help. 
Lots of thanks in advance

[Here is the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeNpe.png)

1- represents first search for column value

2- represents second search for row value

3- represents the output i need

```
      FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(str));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
        for(Row row : sheet)
        {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
           boolean e = EngineList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
           System.out.println(e);
        }
                Row currentRow = datatypeSheet.getRow(0);
                Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(1);
               // System.out.println("crow"+currentRow);

                System.out.println("crow"+cell);
                System.out.println("crowlastcellnum"+currentRow.getLastCellNum());

            if(currentRow.getRowNum()==0)
            {                 
              for(int i=1;i<currentRow.getLastCellNum();i++)  
              {

                if (currentRow.getCell(i).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                    System.out.println(currentRow.getCell(i).getStringCellValue());
                parameterList.add(currentRow.getCell(i).getStringCellValue());
                } 
            }
              System.out.println();
            }

//am getting the row values and column values and stored them into arraylist for search.
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question completely. But, is the below code is what you expecting?

```
FileInputStream excelFile;
Workbook workbook;
try {
    excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

    Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (Row currentRow : datatypeSheet) {
        for (Cell cell : currentRow) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "||");
            } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "||");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thnx for your effort but i sorted that out :)